# Удаление общих подвыражений

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Доброго времени суток!

Столкнулся с такой задачей: есть n уравнений, записанных в символьном виде, необходимо оптимизировать количество операций для их вычисления (пока для простоты подразумевается только сложение). Вот пример:

Исходная система уравнений:

```
x1 = a + b + c
x2 = a + d + c
x3 = a + e + c
```

В результате должно получиться следующее:

```
r1 = a + c
x1 = r1 + b
x2 = r1 + d
x3 = r1 + e
```

Здесь r1 - это замена повторяющейся операции `a + b`. Легко видеть, что количество сложений уменьшилось с 6 до 4. Все это хорошо, но с маленькими уравнениями, а вот когда количество переменных переваливает за несколько сотен - надо писать программу.
Реализовывать алгоритм мне необходимо на C/C++.

После длительного гугления, я выяснил что это называется **common subexpression elimination** (или **удаление общих подвыражений**). Однако, как написать программу или каким именно методом такое можно реализовать я так и не понял. И поэтому придумал свой велоспед. 
Суть велосипеда в следующем:
Входными данными является набор строк. Каждая строка представляет собой одно уравнение, например: `abc` - это `x1 = a + b + c`
Алгоритм действий следующий:

1) упорядочиваем все переменные всех уравнений (ибо он могут быть записаны не по порядку)

2) создаем для каждого уравнения битовый вектор

3) Используя побитовый AND складываем все уравнения и ищем вектор с максимальным количеством установленных бит

4) Добавляем новое уравнение составленное из бит полученных на предыдущем шаге

5) Повторяем все шаги пока не получим нулевой вектор

Я сильно сомневаюсь, что иду правильным путем.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, может кто-то сталкивался с подобными алгоритмами, или натолкнете на идею/книгу/библиотеку?

**P.S.** Сорри если сумбурно, я уже совсем замучался((

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Смотрите, это делается, например, так.

1. Для начала, для преобразований кода вам нужно распарсить его в syntax tree, или в ещё более удобное представление (например, semantic tree). (Это самая лёгкая часть, вам всё равно это понадобится.)
2. Суммы переведите из бинарных в `n`-арные операции. Если одно из слагаемых — сумма, уберите его и добавьте его подслагаемые. То же с разностями. Установите канонический порядок на слагаемых, чтобы не различать `x + 3` и `3 + x`.
3. Составляете список всех подвыражений в дереве путём его рекурсивного обхода.
4. Далее вам нужно ввести порядок на выражениях. Например, вы можете написать хэш-функцию такую, чтобы одинаковые подвыражения обязательно получали одинаковое значение. (Если вы определите хэш-функцию рекурсивно, будет как раз то, что надо.)
5. Вычислите значения хэша на каждом подвыражении (опять-таки рекурсивно). Отсортируйте список по хэшу.
6. Рассматривайте (относительно маленькие) группы с одинаковым хэшем. Определите рекурсивно равенство выражений:

   - высоты деревьев не равны => подвыражения не равны
   - типы корней не совпадают => подвыражения не равны
   - поддеревья не совпадают => подвыражения не равны
   - иначе равны
7. Таким образом, получите список одинаковых подвыражений.
8. Поскольку суммы можно разделить на части по-разному, вычисляйте хэши также для частичных сумм. Достаточно отсортировать слагаемые, и вычислить `2^n` вариантов (включая/не включая каждое из слагаемых). Эти частичные суммы тоже добавляйте в список подвыражений (со ссылкой на оригинальное выражение). При разумном числе слагаемых получится не так уж и много вариантов.

Дерзайте, у вас прекрасное задание!

Comment: @VladD - Вам мое огромное спасибо! Первоначально, у меня тоже были идеи по поводу syntax tree или дерева/списка суффиксов, но я его не стал рассматривать как не очень понятное и неочевидное для меня) В целом я идею понял и постараюсь реализовать в соответствии с Вашими советами. Однако пара вопросов все же есть: конкретно сейчас меня очень интересуют только сложения, кроме того по условиям переменные не могут повторяться в рамках одного уравнения, может все-таки имеет смысл как-то развить мои идеи? И еще, алгоритм, описанный Вами, всегда приводит к глобальному оптимуму или есть исключения?

Comment: @progzdeveloper: На самом деле ваши идеи правильны, просто в моём оформлении должно быть несколько удобнее. Упорядочивание переменных — это как раз и есть приведение слагаемых к каноническому порядку.

Затем, в вашем задании имеют ли право быть ещё коэффициенты при слагаемых? Скажем, не просто `a + b + c`, а `a + 2b + 3c`? От этого зависит, пройдёт ли идея с битовыми векторами.

Comment: @progzdeveloper: Насчёт оптимальности не уверен. Смотрите: пусть у нас есть система

    x1 =      a2 + a3 + a4 + a5
    x2 = a1      + a3 + a4 + a5
    x3 = a1 + a2      + a4 + a5
    x4 = a1 + a2 + a3      + a5
    x5 = a1 + a2 + a3 + a4

Тогда оптимальным было бы, возможно, не нахождение общих подвыражений, а такое решение:

    s = a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5
    xi = s - ai (i = 1..5)

Comment: @VladD

> в вашем задании имеют ли право 
> быть ещё коэффициенты при слагаемых?

В том то и дело, что коэффициентов при слагаемых быть не может - тоже по условию) Просто сама задача в ее оригинальной постановке более простая чем общие подвыражения, поэтому я и занялся битовыми векторами и проч. Просто хотелось бы также знать как быть в наиболее общем случае - и тут Ваш ответ прям в точку!)) Так что еще раз спасибо!)

Comment: Да, и еще кое-что: может имеет смысл по завершению работы над этой задачей сделать исследование? И рассмотреть в нем подробно мой и общий случай. Мне кажется должно получиться интересно)

Comment: @progzdeveloper: обязательно сделайте исследование по результатам разработки! Тема сложная и интересная, думаю, она будет полезна многим.